# Difference between sql statements and clause

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the difference between sql statements and clause

Comment: Statement is a bit of SQL that operates on or returns a set of data. A clause is one small piece of that SQL statement

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following statement:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar JOIN quux WHERE x = y;
```

is made up of the following clauses:

- WHERE x = y
- SELECT foo
- FROM bar
- JOIN quux

Comment: Well, as far as this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefclauses.html) concerns, WHERE and FROM are clauses , SELECT is a statement, and JOIN is an operation.

Comment: @HeyJude What would you call the part of a `SELECT` statement that consists of `SELECT` and the list of expressions to return?

Comment: @Barmar, a [query](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj41360.html)

Comment: [query] indicates that this includes the `FROM` clause. I'm not sure they give a name to just the `SELECT xxx` part.

Comment: @Barmar, I took a closer look into the standard: the capitalized `SELECT` is termed an `<action>`, and the combination of the action and the select list seems to lack a specific name; this combination takes a role as a part of the definitions of several terms, such a "query specification", "select statement: single row", and more.

Comment: @HeyJude I'm not sure the specific terminology is really important outside the standards body. For most purposes, it's enough to distinguish between an entire query/statement and the parts of it that are introduced by each keyword. In casual use, I'm happy to call all of the latter "clauses".

Answer (score 0):

A statement is the query and the clause is the condition of the statement.