# What is difference between clause, command, statement and query in SQL?

Tags: sql, rdbms

Sql Clause, Command and Statement, I see these words are used interchangeably. But they are grammatically different.

I read Some Difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629550/difference-between-sql-statements-and-clause). Already Asked by someone.
Still I am not clear.

The suggested question gives the difference between statement and clause only. And `SELECT foo FROM bar JOIN quux WHERE x = y;' is mentioned as Statement is the answer of that question. I want to Ask then what is the difference between Query and Statement.

So I am wondering what exactly is the difference between them? Or may I just go with the flow? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629550/difference-between-sql-statements-and-clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between sql statements and clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629550/difference-between-sql-statements-and-clause)

Comment: I have read that Question. that you guys have mentioned. Unfortunately I have not enough rating to add my comments on that question to further clarify the things.

Comment: The suggested question gives the difference between statement and clause only. As `SELECT foo FROM bar JOIN quux WHERE x = y;' is mentioned as Statement is the answer. I want to Ask then what is the difference between Query and Statement.

Comment: In my experience these are used interchangeably. There's no hard and fast difference.

Comment: Personally I tend to use query only when data is retrieved (SELECT), statement I *also* use for other 'activities' (CREATE, INSERT etc.). I'm not sure whether its just a personal preference... Further, I use 'script' when multiple statements are involved, again not sure if this is just me

Comment: Right. BTW Nick.McDemaid. Thank you sir for your positive response.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will give you the terminology used with SQL Server. Some of these (certainly the ones in your question) will be extremely common across all database systems, some may be system specific.

From highest level to lowest:

- Script. A single file containing SQL code. May contain multiple batches
- Batch. A batch is the unit in which work is submitted to the server. In SQL Server, each batch is (normally) delimited by `GO`. Splitting the script into batches is a job performed by client tools. A Batch may contain multiple statements.
- Statement (a.k.a Command<sup>1</sup> or Query). This is the smallest unit of individual work that the server will work with. I.e. Every statement is something "complete", which will cause the server to perform some work and may result in data being modified and/or a result set being returned. Typically, the server will compile each statement individually (but may do each compilation for every statement in a Batch before any of them are executed).
- Clause<sup>2</sup>. A Clause is a subunit of a statement - but, beware, some statements may consist of only a single Clause, which may appear to muddy the waters a little. For example, some database systems will accept `SELECT 10;` as a Query. This is a `SELECT` statement consisting only of a `SELECT` clause. Multiple statement types may use the same clause types. E.g. Both `SELECT` and `DELETE` statements may contain a `WHERE` clause. Also, most statements will have a clause that shares the same name.
- Expression<sup>2</sup>. An expression is something that produces a scalar value (Note though that, in most contexts, this is understood to be "one scalar value per row", not "one scalar value in total")

  - Predicate. A boolean expression, most often encountered in `WHERE` clauses, `WHEN` clauses and `CHECK` constraints. These are especially called out because not all database systems support a user visible boolean data type, and so they're not always treated the same as other expressions.

---

<sup>1</sup>Many client libraries will expose some kind of command object for submitting queries to the database system. However, to muddy the waters further, many of these will accept a batch. Nevertheless, command seems to have stuck as having a similar meaning as statement, possible because in the vast majority of cases, the command object isn't used for multiple statements in one go.

<sup>2</sup>Note that to some extent, these share the same level. A `SELECT` clause may contain a `CASE` expression, that consists of multiple `WHEN` and `THEN` clauses.

Comment: alot of things now make sense. Thanks for an amazing answer.